# The value for task ':authority:test' property 'testFrameworkProperty' is final

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit4, junit5, junit-jupiter

Please help with the below issue. I found a similar query in stackoverflow but their build.gradle code totally different with mine and that solution not working for me.

The same code working fine with gradle version 7.5.1 but not working with gradle 8.0.2.
And We are using below Junit libraries.

```
org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.1
org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1
org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.1
org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.9.1
```

**error:**

**The value for task ':authority:test' property 'testFrameworkProperty' is final and cannot be changed any further.**

task in build.gradle file:

```
test{
  group= 'tddtest'
  description='Execute All TDD Unit Test cases'
  reports.html.outputLocation=file("reports/tdd/html")
  reports.junitXml.outputLocation=file("reports/tdd/xml")
  useJunit {
    includeCategories 'com.jb.controller.testCategory.TDDTest'
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's a single letter change, at least it works when I try it with Gradle >= 8.0.2:

```
reports.junitXml.outputLocation=file("reports/tdd/xml")
```

`junitxml` -> `junitXml`

Comment: Thanks for the response. My apologies, it was a typo error in the post. I have corrected the post now. I was not able to copy paste the code, so while typing I made this mistake.

Comment: Since it works here, something else than just the Gradle version must have changed or be relevant for what you observe.

Comment: In another gradle build file name with 'subjprojects.gradle' we have the below script. Is this script have anything to do with another file's script where we have 'useJunit'?              test{                                                                                                                                                  useJunitPlatform{                                                                                                                includeEngines 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'                                                                                  }}